# child_process.exec producing "♀" character

Tags: node.js

I have a simple child_process.exec statement and its output (stdout) always has a "♀" character at the beginning for some reason

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('echo hi', function (err, stdout) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

[[image: scr]]

My node is v0.12 and I also have iojs installed which is v2.3. I've tested with both separately with same result. I've also tested it in different consoles -  cmd.exe, powershell, and Git's sh.exe, same result.

Is this character supposed to be present? If not, what might be producing it?

Comment: Congratulations, it's a girl! And it talks already

Comment: I've actually tried it in cmd.exe right now, I have the usual expected output, could you paste more code please?

Comment: @aduch That's all the code there is really, it's just a simple 4 line test script to test just that.

Comment: @aduch What node version do you have?

Comment: v0.12.7 (fresh install, gotta admit)

Comment: And what happens if you do it another time:
echo hi && echo hi?

Comment: @Vico For `echo hi && echo hi` the output is `♀hi hi` (second 'hi' is in next line and without the '♀' character). So ♀ is only added once, at the beginning of the entire output.

Comment: I don't have the answer to your problem, it seems that stdout is not really empty. You have to find a way to flush it first. 
If it's just echoing in stdout, maybe using process.stdout.write("hi"); could solve the problem?

Comment: Whether or not this symbol when displaying the result of another operating system commands? For example, a directory listing?

Comment: @stdob-- It appears on all commands, `dir`, `ls`. In fact it appears even if I don't supply any command (`exec(''`).

Comment: @Vico Tried adding `process.stdout.write("hi");` prior to exec, and the exec still adds ♀, even though process.stdout.write prints just "hi", meaning stdout was indeed empty this time? [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ZYtgyiM.png)

Comment: @laggingreflex Which operating system and what version is this happening? How exactly do you run this code from the command line? If you run this `node -e "require('child_process').exec('echo hi', function (err, stdout) { console.log(stdout); });"` - are this symnol present?

Comment: @stdob-- Windows 8.1. I run it normally, `node.exe index.js` with the file only having those 4 lines of code. And yes, that command also produced "♀hi". Even in REPL mode it has the same result

Comment: I don't know what this might mean, but the `♀` symbol in code page 437 (commonly used in console windows on Windows) is 0x0c - a formfeed.

Answer (score 0):

According to `child_process`'s the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.12.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), the object passed to `stdout` is a buffer object. You need to decode it before printing it out as a string.

I modified your code to demonstrate how to do that. The symbol no longer appears in my console.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

exec('echo hi', function (err, stdout) {
    var message = decoder.write(stdout);
    console.log(message.trim());
});
```

For more detail about string decoder, you could always look at the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.12.x/api/string_decoder.html)